# Why is my Linq GroupBy query not returning correct count values?

Tags: c#, linq, csv, datatable

The following code reads a CSV file into a DataTable. It then loops thru all the columns in the DataTable and tries to generate a count of all the distinct values in each column using the Linq query:

```
var g = allValues.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i);
```

Why is the "grp.Count()" value never greater than 1 even though I know all the columns contain duplicate values?

```
        private void button13_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = GetDataFromCSVFile(-1);

        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

        int test = 0;
        string[] columnToSearch = { "" };

        IList<ColumnDetail> colDetails = new List<ColumnDetail>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            columnToSearch[0] = col.ToString();

            DataTable allValues = GetAllValuesFromColumn(table, columnToSearch);

            var g = allValues.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i);

            test = 0;
            foreach (var grp in g)
            {
                if (grp.Count() > 1)
                    MessageBox.Show(" grp.Key.ItemArray[0].ToString() : " + grp.Key.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " Cnt: " + grp.Count());
                test++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Count is: " + test);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `DataRow` are not based on the values of each row, but on the object's reference.  Two rows that have the same column values are not equal.  You will need to create a custom `IEqualityComparer` to compare the rows based on the values of each column instead.

In this particular case, a suitable implementation has already been written in the form of the `DataRowComparer` class, so you can just use `DataRowComparer.Default` as the `IEqualityComparer` when grouping to group based on the value of the rows instead of the reference to the rows.

Comment: Thanks Servy. That solved my problem. I modified the line:                                                                     var g = allValues.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i);                                                                                                                                      to                                                                      var g = allValues.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i, DataRowComparer.Default);